# python equivalent of head/grep/tail

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python, so trying to convert these three bash script lines into the python way (maybe into a class I guess?). I want to take the 3 outputs of these commands and put them all into 3 variables to put in a mysql database, rather than just putting the results in a txt file and reading later:

```
head -n 14 /usr/src/project/logs/some.log > tacos.txt
grep 'name' /usr/src/project/logs/some.log | grep -v 'result=""' | grep -v 'result="is\ OK"' >> tacos.txt
tail -n 5 /usr/src/project/logs/some.log >> tacos.txt
```

I have the mysql connector working in python to put the variables into a database later, but I don't know how to "unbash" the head/grep/tail portion into python. I don't quite understand if there's python equivalents.

Comment: You should really provide information on your attempts.  Simply asking us to implement methods for you to emulate existing behavior or functionality in other languages will be (generally) poorly received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as UNIX developers did, you'll need to write the supporting functions.  `head` and `tail` are executable programs, not atomic system commands.  `grep` is even more complex, being the system regular expression facility.

Look up what you need in `regex` for Python (or almost any high-level language).  For `head` and `tail`, you'll need to write simply functions that read the file or input stream ... just as UNIX does in the underlying code.  These are not built-in commands in general-purpose languages.

Do keep in mind that you're switching paradigms.  Shell programming is specifically canted for the central purpose of an OS: managing system resources.  When you translate such things to a general-purpose language, you will gain many general-purpose facilities, but lose many powerful routines for direct manipulation of OS objects.

Also look into Python's modules [os](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) and [system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html); you may find that it's most effective to simply invoke the OS from within Python:

```
taco_str = os.system("head -n 14 ...")
taco_str += os.system("grep ...")
taco_str += os.system("tail -n 5 ...")
```

and the write `taco_str` to the desired file.